# Redirect current tab to a new URL

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension

im making a simple extension, and i want my current tab, to be relocated to a new loaction, but this code doesnt work for me:

```
function redirect() {
    console.log("HELLO"); 
    chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
        var currentURL = tab.url;
        if(currentURL == "http://example.site/"){
            chrome.tabs.create("http://newlocation.site/",tab);
            alert("redirected");
        }
    });
}

chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(redirect);
```

Anyhow, i cant google for informations about properties, of the slected tab. Are there any `tab.url` like "command"? I mean, tab.reload() .. and so on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*After fixing your current code, a new tab will be created when the current tab matches the given URL.*

1. [`chrome.tabs.create(object createInfo, function callback)`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#method-create) is the correct signature.
2. Note: `chrome.tabs.getSelected` [is deprecated](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/whats_new.html#16) in favour of `chrome.tabs.query`.

   ```
   chrome.tabs.create({url: "http://newlocation.site/"});
   ```

This code works as intended (background script):

```
function redirect() {
    console.log("Querying...");
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true}, function(tabArray) {
        var currentURL = tabArray[0].url;
        // For debugging purposes:
        console.log(currentURL);
        if (currentURL == "http://example.site/") {
            // The next line is the important change
            chrome.tabs.create({url: "http://newlocation.site/"});
            alert("redirected");
        }
    });
}
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(redirect);
```

If you don't want to create a new tab, but change the URL of the current tab, use `update` instead of `create`:

```
chrome.tabs.update(tabArray[0].id, {url: "http://newlocation.site/"});
```

### Documentation

- [`chrome.tabs.create`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#method-create)
- [`chrome.tabs.query`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#method-query)
- [`chrome.tabs.update`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#method-update)
- The [`Tab` object](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#type-Tab)